# catch key and trigger function using jQuery or plain js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea inside a form:

```
<textearea id="message"></textarea>
```

While typing, whenever a user types the character **#** inside the textarea, I want to trigger a function for every character typed afterwards and till the user hits enter or space bar.

How is this possible using jQuery or plain JS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
var myCallback = function () {
    //put your code here
}

(function (callback) {
    var jMessage = $('#message'),
        callbackCallable = false,
        keycodeEnter = 13,
        keycodeSpace = 32;


    jMessage.keyup(function (e) {
        var lastLetter = jMessage.val().slice(-1);
        if (lastLetter === '#') {
            callbackCallable = true;
        } else if (e.keyCode === keycodeEnter || e.keyCode === keycodeSpace) {
            callbackCallable = false;
        } else if (callbackCallable) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}(myCallback));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect only typing you can listen for a key pressed event.

```
var anyHitYet = false;
jQuery('#massage').keydown(function (event) {

    if (anyHitYet) return;

    var key = event.keyCode;
    if (key === 51) {
        //call your function here
    } else if (key === 13 || key === 32) {
        anyHitYet = true;
    }
});
```

Basically if it's 51 then `#` is hit so call your function if `space` or `enter` are hit your `#`-when-pressed-function won't be executed until you make `anyHitYet=false` again

Somebody might paste something though so then it is a different story

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the above answers do what the OP wants.
I think a second or third # should be monitored aswell, till a space or return ends monitoring.

```
// have a flag somewhere and initialize it to FALSE
var doMonitor = FALSE; 

$('#message').keydown(function(event){

    // trigger monitoring after # was tipped
    // (only once till space or return reset)
    if(event.keyCode == 51 && !doMonitor){
       doMonitor = TRUE;
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13)
       doMonitor = FALSE;
    else if(doMonitor){
        // do whatever needs to be done
    }
});
```

You may also add an attribute to your #message textarea and remove it (or change its value)  instead of using a variable.

```
// for setting an attribute
.attr( attributeName, value )

// for removing it
.removeattr( attributeName )
```

look here http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/ and here http://api.jquery.com/attr/